# Converges sequence and Cauchy sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

I try to solve this(9) but I am not sure if true or not?[image]

Comment: Why not $d(x_n',l) \leq d(x_n',x_n) + d(x_n,l)$, Take the limit on both sides then $d(x_n',x_n') \to 0$ because of eq. seq. and $d(x_n,l) \to 0$ because of convergence.

Comment: I agree with @Olba12, also I would refrain from saying $x_n$ and $x_n^{'}$ are arbitrary, they certainly are chosen with specific properties.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Without further investigation, you do not know whether $(x_n')$ converges since the completeness of $X$ is not specified.

Suppose you can assume this. Then why $d(\ell, x) < \varepsilon$ without any assumptions? From your inequality I at most get $\lim d(x_n, x_n')\leqslant d(\ell, x)$ which is trivially true, hence useless.

A better approach is what mentioned in comment by @Olba12.